# Using `N` gives strange result

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider these two functions which are almost the same:

```
 f[x_] := N@
  Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[x - z], {z, 0, x}]]

g[x_] := 
Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[x - z], {z, 0, x}]]
```

The first function has this extra command: `N@`

`f[{1, 2}]` returns:

```
  {{{0.420735, 1.22404}, {0.100612, 0.909297}}}
```

`N@g[{1, 2}]` returns:

```
{{0.420735, 0.909297}}
```

and,

```
N@Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[1 - z], {z, 0, 1}] = 0.420735
N@Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[1 - z], {z, 0, 2}] = 1.22404
N@Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[2 - z], {z, 0, 1}] = 0.100612
N@Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[2 - z], {z, 0, 2}] = 0.909297
```

it seems `f` uses a combination of `1` and `2` and put each in the `x` in `Cos` and the upper limit of integral independently. 
Does anybody know why it happens?

Comment: Maybe removing `Table` gives a simpler example without eliminating the issue you raise?

Comment: ... or more simply `f[x_] := N@Evaluate[Integrate[x - z, {z, 0, x}]]; g[x_] := Evaluate[Integrate[x - z, {z, 0, x}]]`.

Comment: @kguler. You are right here the `Table` does not an effect. I will correct that later.

Comment: Interesting ... Don't think I have seen this before: `Integrate[z + {a, b}, {z, {r, s}, {t, u}}]` threads over `{{a,b},{r,s},{t,u}}`. More generally, it seems to do so if the the integrand is `Listable`: i.e., if foo is `Listable`, then `Integrate[foo[z, {a, b}], {z, {r, s}, {t, u}}]` threads, not just over `{a,b}`, but over `{{a,b},{r,s},{t,u}}`

Comment: By the way, it's not the fault of `N` except insofar as it prevents `Evaluate` from doing anything (because `Evaluate` is no longer immediately under the `:=`). The real reason for the difference is that in `g` the integral is pre-evaluated while in `f` it is not.

Comment: @RahulNarain Isn't that the answer?

Comment: @Michael, I think it's part of the answer. kguler's comment is the other, more interesting part.

Comment: @RahulNarain, somehow it's not that surprising to me.  I think the antiderivative is just being evaluated at the list(s) being passed as "end points."

Answer (score 1):

From the "Details" section of the documentation for `Evaluate`: "`Evaluate` only overrides `HoldFirst`, etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held." and from the "Possible Issues" section: "`Evaluate` works only on the first level, directly inside a held function."

```
f[x_] := N@Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[x - z], {z, 0, x}]]

?f
```

> Global`f
>
> f[x_] := N[Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[x - z], {z, 0, x}]]]

```
f[{x1, x2}]
```

> {{0.5 x1 Sin[x1], 
>     0.25 (Cos[x1] - 1. Cos[x1 - 2. x2] + 
>        2. x2 Sin[x1])}, {0.25 (-1. Cos[2. x1 - 1. x2] + Cos[x2] + 
>        2. x1 Sin[x2]), 0.5 x2 Sin[x2]}}

```
 g[x_] := Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[z]*Cos[x - z], {z, 0, x}]]
```

> ?g
>
> Global`g
>
> g[x_] := (x*Sin[x])/2

```
g[{x1, x2}] == f /@ {x1, x2}
```

> True

```
N@g[{x1, x2}] === f /@ {x1, x2}
```

> True